# (Why) is the real life observation space spherical?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, coordinate-systems, antennas

It is a quite philosophical question. To explain it, let's consider a dish antenna radiating a EM field like in the following picture:

[image]

Let's image you are an observer who can look the antenna radiation pattern from the point P.

Such a EM field distribution in space is often described through two different coordinate systems:

1. Spherical ($\theta, \phi$ or Azimuth, Elevation). Its polar 3d plot looks like that (I got it through sph2cart in Matlab):

[image]

2. Cartesian(through the director cosines u,v)

[image]

**It's very straightforward that an observer placed at the point P will see the polar plot and not the cartesian plot, but why?** Let's note also that in the cartesian plot, only a "visibility circle" corresponds to the real spherical directions. The other directions outside this circle (and inside the unit square) are not considered as they are not real ($\theta, \phi$ angles are imaginary for such director cosines values). Such a circle corresponds to the central cut of the spherical coordinate system. **It's a hint that the real world works with spherical coordinates: but why?**

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly how the second plot is designed, but isn't the first plot's idea that we fix the observer's distance to some fixed value and only consider the dependence of the direction? We could, of course, also consider the dependence on the distance, but we don't, because it's trivial (inverse square dependency). Things would look different, if the source was  not point-like, but, say, an infinite straight line. Then we'd rather use cylindrical and not spherical coordinates and fix the corresponding radial coordinate.

Comment: I believe Photon is right. Both plots convey the same information, albeit in a different visual representation. In both cases (if we can consider the two different plots as distinct cases, which in my opinion are **not**) we talk about the exact same thing. If you were to place the observer somewhere in the second plot (this is find its Cartesian coordinates) the result would be exactly the same. So, this is more of a different way to represent "reality".